# How do I append a href to an item that has a hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

My app pulls images from instagram, and I am wondering how I can use JS to cycle through the document and simply look for every item that has a `#` hashtag and append a URL to it.

i.e.

```
My instagram photo contains the following tags #instagram #photo #tags
```

and the result ends up looking like

My instagram photo contains the following tags [#instagram](http://myapp.com/tag/instagram) [#photo](http://myapp.com/tag/photo) [#tags](http://myapp.com/tag/tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = "My instagram photo contains the following tags #instagram #photo #tags";

var split = x.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i< split.length; i++){
    if(split[i].indexOf('#') >= 0){
        split[i] = '<a href=\"http://myapp.com/tag/'+split[i].substring(1)+'\">'+split[i]+'</a>';
    }
}
console.log(split.join(" "));
```

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9XQBC/

Answer (score 0):

u can append one # to href,
try this

```
var tag = '#instagram';

$('.myPhoto').attr('href',tag);//this will change current href
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution

```
hashtag_regexp = /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

function linkHashtags(text) {
    return text.replace(
        hashtag_regexp,
        '<a class="hashtag" href="/search?q=$1">#$1</a>'
    );
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').each(function() {
        $(this).html(linkHashtags($(this).html()));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over each anchor link, test for the presence of a hash tag, and then change the URL based on a 'true' condition.

```
$.each($('a'), function(i,v){
  var findHash = /#/g;
  var scenario = findHash.test($(v).attr('href'));
  if(scenario == true){
    var grabHref = $(v).attr('href');
    var addHref = 'somethingafterthehash';
    $(v).attr('href', grabHref + addHref);
     console.log($(v).attr('href'));
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b2MTV/)

Comment: There is no anchor, OP wants to add them.

Comment: @Florian Margaine where does it say that?